# None of the chartist plugins are working

Tags: chartist.js

I have a working chartist Line chart and I have configured the plugins as suggested in documentations. I don't get any errors when loading the page. Its just that nothing gets reflected on the chart according to plugin. I have added two plugins - they don't show any error and my line chart shows perfectly fine.

But I see no effect of those plugins - tooltip plugin and pointlabel plugin.

And yes they are loaded in the HTML and their css files are also included else would have got errors about plugins not being present.

```
var options = {
    low: 0,
    high: 100,
    showGridBackground: false,
    showArea: true,
    axisX: {
        showGrid: false
    },
    axisY: {
    },
    plugins: [
        Chartist.plugins.ctPointLabels({
            textAnchor: 'middle',
            labelInterpolationFnc: function(value) {console.log("i was called"); return '$' + value}
        }),
        Chartist.plugins.tooltip({
        })
    ]
};

var m = new Chartist.Line('#myChart', data, options);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is simple working example using your code. One thing to watch out for is that the tooltips need additional CSS to display correctly.

https://jsfiddle.net/rxdb576n/1/

```js
var data = {
  labels: ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed"],
  series: [
    [10, 20, 75]
  ],
}

var options = {
  low: 0,
  high: 100,
  showGridBackground: false,
  showArea: true,
  axisX: {
    showGrid: false
  },
  axisY: {},
  plugins: [
    Chartist.plugins.ctPointLabels({
      textAnchor: 'middle',
      labelInterpolationFnc: function(value) {
        console.log("i was called");
        return '$' + value
      }
    }),
    Chartist.plugins.tooltip({

    })
  ]
};

var m = new Chartist.Line('#myChart', data, options);
```

```css
.chartist-tooltip {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 20px 0 0 10px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.chartist-tooltip.tooltip-show {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartist/0.11.0/chartist.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartist/0.11.0/chartist.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/chartist-plugin-tooltips@0.0.17"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/chartist-plugin-pointlabels@0.0.6"></script>
<div id="myChart"></div>
```